# Нужно ли использовать умные указатели для стековых переменных?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Интересно узнать мнения людей намного более опытных, чем я. Нужно ли использовать умные указатели для стековых переменных? С точки зрения технической необходимости - думаю, что не нужно (а зачем?), но возможно это является неким стандартом и обязаловом у опытных разработчиков. Обоснуйте свой ответ, пожалуйста. Спасибо!
Что я подразумеваю под "стековые переменные" :

```
int main () 
{
    int i = 0;   
    int * ptr = &i; 
}
```

Comment: Это называется не стековые переменные, а переменные с автоматическим временем хранения. А умные указатели используются для объектов с динамическим временем хранения (то бишь для созданных при помощи `new` или особой функции создания).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Умные указатели нужны (в первую очередь) для того, чтобы автоматически освобождать выделенную **в куче** память (когда сам указатель уничтожается). Грубо говоря, они вызывают `delete` за вас.

`int i` - на стеке, а не в куче, поэтому ему не нужен `delete`, поэтому умный указатель тут не нужен.

Попытка вызвать `delete` на `i` (либо вами, либо умным указателем) вызовет неопределенное поведение, и скорее всего краш.

Умный указатель можно заставить не делать `delete`, но с тем же успехом можно взять сырой указатель.

---

> возможно это является неким стандартом и обязаловом у опытных разработчиков

Это [неправильный](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) подход. Если в чем-то нет практического смысла, то неважно, является это стандартом или нет. И наоборот.

Answer (score 2):

> Нужно ли использовать умные указатели для стековых переменных?

Если вы поймете, что такое умные указатели, то вопрос отпадет сам собой. Умные указатели представляют собой механизм **владения** (по английски ownership) ресурсом. Обычно этот ресурс - динамически созданные объекты, но этим дело не ограничивается. Вы можете довольно просто использовать умные указатели для владения сокетом, дескриптором базы данных итд итп. При этом `std::unqiue_ptr` предоставляет модель владения с уникальным владельцем (отсюда и имя), `std::shared_ptr` предоставляет разделяюмую (shared) модель владения.

Теперь, можете ли вы владеть автоматическими переменными (aka созданными на стеке)? Нет не можете, их время жизни определяется компилятором. Отсюда не имеет смысла создавать "умные" указатели на ресурсы, время жизни которых вы не контроллируете.

Здесь есть небольшое исключение - вам почему либо нужно в функцию, которая ожидает умный указатель передать указатель на автоматическую или статическую переменную. Такой путь чреват проблемами и не стоит так делать, но жизнь есть жизнь. В этом случае можно создать умный указатель с  очищающей функцией "пустышкой". Но это стоит делать только в крайнем случае, если просто нет другого выхода.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нет такого требования. Более того, стандарт не требует, что бы умные указатели обязательно использовались вообще.

Также, если Вы чуточку присмотритесь, то станет очевидно, что завернуть переменную на стеке в умный указатель чревато большими проблемами - по факту выхода с области видимости деструктор может быть вызван дважды! а это очень и очень плохо. А специально вызывать ручками reset как то не очень хорошо.

Но если использовать умные указатели по назначению, то сам умный указатель может быть на стеке, а объект, который он держит внутри - в хипе. И это часто используется. Например, если сам объект не есть с++ классом и нам нужно ручками его "удалить". В этом случае заворачивание в умный указатель с "удалятором" (делитером) работает очень хорошо.

Также может быть ситуация, что объект, который Вы создаете, может хотеть покинуть область видимости. В этом случае умный указатель самое оно.